# Use VBA to find the Row Number Based on the File Name

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a code to let VBA find the current open file name then look up the excel sheet to find the cell that has exactly same value.
Since the file type is .dgn type, I try to use FileSystemObject. But I am stuck on how to write it to read current open file name.

After finding the matching cell, I would like to carry out the row number of that cell.

Regards,

Comment: Please see [ask] and [reprex], then [edit] your question as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that "current open file name" means the name of the workbook that the VBA code is in.

Furthermore, let's assume that your data is stored on a worksheet called "Sheet1".  For this example, the range of data looks like this:

[image: Range of data used for example]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Answer()

    ' Get the name of this document
    Dim DocumentName As String
    DocumentName = ThisWorkbook.Name
    
    ' Search for the name of the document in the range
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4")

    Dim CellAddress As String
    CellAddress = FindCell(CellRange:=MyRange, SearchContent:=DocumentName)
    
    ' Output the result as a message
    MsgBox "The first cell with " & DocumentName & " in it is at " & CellAddress

End Sub


Private Function FindCell(CellRange As Range, SearchContent As String) As String

    ' Return the cell address of the first cell found in CellRange that has
    ' CellContent in it
    
    ' Iterate through the range
    Dim Cell As Variant
    For Each Cell In CellRange
    
        If Cell.Value = SearchContent Then
        
            FindCell = Cell.Address
            Exit Function
        
        End If
    
    Next Cell

End Function
```

I created a function called `FindCell` which returns the cell address of the first cell in a range that matches the data that we are searching for.  In this example, we are searching for the first cell that has this workbook's name (which I have called "Book1").

As other users have pointed out, please include more detail when you ask questions.  I have had to make a few large assumptions to put this example together.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I am wondering whether there is a way to get the document name if the file type is not excel. Shall I use FSO?
    'Find File Name in the Excel Sheet and Get Row Number'
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FileName = FSO.GetFileName("C:\ExamplePath\ExampleFile.txt")
    MsgBox FileName
How can I use FSO. GetFileName but to the current active file?

Comment: I suggest first googling a bit to see if anyone has done this before.  If you find nothing, then ask a new question, with more detail, and an example of your code.  My answer had the limitation that we are working only in Excel.